# How to define a connected bipartite graph?

Tags: graph-theory

I know what a connected graph is - "A graph is connected when there is a path between every pair of vertices". But I am skeptical about how to define a connected bipartite graph. Is the following correct?
"When every vertex in the first subset has a edge with every vertex in the second subset"

Please comment. Need help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connected bipartite graph is a graph fulfilling both, following conditions:

1. Vertices can be divided into two disjoint sets U and V (that is, U and V are each independent sets) such that every edge in graph connects a vertex in U to one in V.
2. There is a path between every pair of vertices, regardless of the set that they are in.

> Is the following correct? "When every vertex in the first subset has a
>   edge with every vertex in the second subset"

No it't not:

```
o----o
    / 
   /
  /
o----o
```

This is a connected bipartite graph and it's not fulfilling Your definition.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Tony
Okay, so given a connected bipartite graph having n vertices and m edges, what would be the minimum value of m? will it be 1?

Comment: Minimal value of `m` for graph to stay connected is `n-1`. For example it can be one long line of vertices or a star with one vertex inside and `n-1` outside. Both those graphs are bipartite.

Comment: Thanks again Tony. But I am confused. If the vertices get divided into 2 subsets of n/2, wont the minimal value of m be n/2 which is smaller than n-1?

Comment: The minimal value of m for graph to stay connected is n-1. You can't have a connected graph with n/2 edges (unless n = 2 :) ). It can be bipartite (even with less edges) but it won't be connected.

Comment: Technically a graph without edges is bipartite too - the only condition for graph to be bipartite is that if the edge exists it has to be between the U and V subsets.

Comment: Thanks Tony
As you said in your first comment. A connected bipartite graph is a graph which satisfies - "There is a path between every pair of vertices, regardless of the set that they are in."

Comment: I got it now Tony. Thanks a lot for clearing my doubt. I tried some examples and tried connecting the n vertices which are divided into different ratios between the two subsets and I came up with n-1 edges as the minimal quantity to get the graph connected. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: There is a difference between a path and an edge, I hope that You understand everything now. If you feel that my answer helped you, you could [accept my answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).